# Where are source files for Due?

Tags: arduino-due

Where are the source files containing the definitions and the HAL functions located for the Due?

I am trying to do CMSIS programming.

Comment: There is an interesting discussion about Hardware Abstraction Layers (HAL) on Reddit’s r/Arduino. They assert that the Arduino environment as a whole is a HAL. https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/2y61su/when_would_you_start_caring_about_the_hal/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf

Comment: There is also an interesting discussion on the Arduino forum about getting started with the common microcontroller interface standard (CMSIS) https://forum.arduino.cc/t/anyone-using-cmsis-how-to-get-started/226150

Comment: Also there are a number of CMSIS libraries available for Arduino.

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino Core for supporting Arduino Due is called ArduinoCore-Sam, which can be found at https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-sam, inside the `system` directory, you will find the CMSIS device driver.